# PHP: how to create an image from another PNG image

Tags: php, png, gd

I have a small Minecraft server where people can upload their skins. Minecraft skins are small png images. Is it possible to convert this png image to another png image via PHP (e.g. GD library)?

I have made this image to help me explain what I am trying to do:

[image: Minecraft skin php converter]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You'd need multiple [imagecopy](http://php.net/imagecopy) commands to pull out sections of the skin image and paste it into the proper spots in the "output" image.

Basic order of operations would be:

```
$input = imagecreatefrompng('skin.png');
$output = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 600); // whatever the dimensions should be.

imagecopy($output, $input, 0,0, 10,20, 50,60);
imagecopy(...);
...
...
```

The first copy command is saying "take a 50x60 section of the input image, starting at coordinates 10x20, and paste it into the destination image in the top left corner".

The actual sequence/coordinates/sizes will be up to you to figure out.

If you're not doing a 1:1 copy of the image and are doing resizing, then you'll want [`imagecopyresampled()`](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled) instead.

Comment: I was going to suggest this too.

Comment: I was going to suggest this as well. Pfff

Answer (score 1):

Here is the PHP manual for creating images from png :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php

Here is a simple tutorial :

http://www.phptutorial.info/?imagecreatefrompng

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS

Here is a tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but im looking for a PHP solution to create a permanent image of the skin